# String permutation using iteration and a filter

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm looking to improve my skills as a developer so I recently challenged myself to design a string permutation generator without recursion. To add to the algorithm I also decided that the string should have a filter to it. An example of a filter would be "lld" where "l" is any character a-z and "d" is any digit 0-9. The filter "lld" should produce all strings aa0-zz9. Would love feedback on how to improve this algo. Thanks.

### Implementation in C++

```
#include <iostream>

#define CHAR_SET_LEN 26
#define INT_SET_LEN 10
#define FILTER_LEN 3

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    char char_set[CHAR_SET_LEN] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    char int_set[INT_SET_LEN] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

    bool doLoop = true;

    int filterStack[100];

    int filterLength = FILTER_LEN;

    char filter[FILTER_LEN+1] = "lld";

    for (int i=0; i < filterLength; i++) {
        filterStack[i] = 0;
    }

    while (doLoop) {
        char string[FILTER_LEN];

        for (int a = 0; a < filterLength; a++) {
            if (filter[a] == 'l') {
                string[a] = char_set[filterStack[a]];
            }
            else {
                string[a] = int_set[filterStack[a]];
            }

        }
//
        std::cout << string << std::endl;
//
        for (int z = (filterLength-1); z > -1; z--) {
            filterStack[z] = filterStack[z] + 1;

            int finalFilter = INT_SET_LEN;
            if (filter[z] == 'l') {
                finalFilter = CHAR_SET_LEN;
            }

            if (filterStack[z] < finalFilter) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                if (z == 0 && (filterStack[z] == finalFilter)) {
                    doLoop = false;
                    break;
                }

                filterStack[z] = 0;
            }
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need `char string[FILTER_LEN + 1]; string[FILTER_LEN] = '\0'` to create a null-terminated string. If your `std::cout << string` works, it's by chance.

Comment: Alternatively, create a standard string: `std::string(string, sizeof string)`.  You might want to rename your variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Are you sure this is C++?

...because this is almost 100% C. Let's go over some things:

1. `#define` is discouraged in modern C++, as is reliance on the C preprocessor in general. Just define your constants with `const` and (depending on the situation) `constexpr`.
2. Don't define raw arrays. Use `std::array` for fixed size arrays, `std::vector` for dynamic arrays, or any other standard container class.
3. Don't use `char` arrays if you mean strings. C++ offers `std::string` for general string handling and `std::stringstream` for string building.
4. Use standard algorithms. For example, your first for-loop could be replaced with a call to `std::fill`.

That said, there are

## Other Issues

1. Don't use `std::endl`. `'\n'` does the same thing, but doesn't include the unnecessary flush `std::endl` comes with.
2. You don't need `char_set` and `int_set`. You can generate all lowercase letter by adding their offset in the alphabet to `'a'` (i.e. `'a' + 1 == 'b'`) thanks to the (almost) ubiquitous ASCII encoding. The same is true for digits.
3. `int` is not the right type for index variables. Use somethings more appropriate, such as `std::size_t`, instead.
4. You should export some of your code to proper functions. Just putting everything into `main` makes your code hard to read and prone to bugs.
5. As Cris Luengo pointed out in the comments already, `string` is not null-terminated, and thus you're causing undefined behavior when writing it to `std::cout`.
6. `filter` is one character longer than it needs to be. Since you never do something with it that would require it to be null terminated (and don't even null terminate the string, just keep an unused character at the end), it suffices to make its length `FILTER_LEN`.

Comment: You're right. I seem to have one toe in C and one in C++. Will clean that up. Really this should be C

Comment: Well, C++17 `std::string_view` is preferable to `std::string` where applicable.

Comment: @Deduplicator It is, but I don't think it is applicable here (except for `filter` maybe).

Comment: @Deduplicator, due to its absence of ownership semantics, I'd prefer to use it only in template metaprogramming context, or in cases where doing otherwise will complicate things.

Comment: @Incomputable: For best effect, use it in any and all contexts where the callee shall not acquire ownership, and preferentially in contexts where it wraps a string-literal. It's absence of ownership is its greatest strength.